# Is interdocument referencing possible with pandoc and LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

More of a theory question I suppose.

Say I have 3 documents - `story1`, `story2`, `storyBible`. Each document renders to PDF fine, and they're all valid documents that `bookdown` (and therefore`pandoc`, `pandoc-citeproc`, etc.) are happy with.

My question is: in `book-bible`, say I wanted to write a passage about a character - we'll call him *Hero.* In chapter 4 of `story1`, Hero does a heroic deed.

What I'd like to achieve in the end is to put some (invisible when rendered) marker in `story1`'s source that allows for `storyBible` to reference it in the spirit of the following:

```
In Heroes Among Us*, Hero accomplishes a heroic deed**. This deed leads to consequences***.

* Chapter 4 of story1
** story1, p. 20-21
*** story2, p. 410-411
```

Essentially, can I generate references to text in another document? It is important that they are dynamic (even if I have to run a generation script to compile them) and require minimal-to-no manual intervention.

I figure it's probably something in the vicinity of BibTex? But I haven't seen anyone - or perhaps I haven't used the exact keywords with Google - discuss references to unpublished text. I suppose people generally like to refer to things others can *actually read,* but then consider me the exception to the rule :^)

Can this be done? If not with bookdown's stack, then where or what else can I try?

Cheers.

Comment: Such cross referencing is done in latex with the xr package.

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll check that out